# Upgrading CXF and WSS4J but can't find dependencies

Tags: java, maven, cxf, wss4j

So I have a working project that I am trying to upgrade CXF and WSS4J

It looks like I have upgraded my client ok, but that's because I am using this for wss4j:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.wss4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.8</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

But my server is throwing ClassNotFound exceptions,  obviously because of the type=pom.

So where do I find the new classes jars?  Specifically WSPasswordCallback.

BTW,  I am using CXF 3.1.9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that they moved everything.  The first place you want to look is:  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.wss4j

That is where all the new ones are.  From there you will simply need to google the class you want and see if you can find the package you need.  For me WSPasswordCallback moved to the commons package...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.wss4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>wss4j-ws-security-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

IMHO this could have been handled better, but it's a start to find what you need.